# Using import or require in the browser file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, shopify, node-modules

I'm using react and nextjs to develop my app for Shopify store. In this app, I'm creating a script tag(SHOPIFY API) which adds some functionality to the storefront and stores some data from there. Now, I want to store that data in some file for which I need to import or require some node module, but when I use "import" statement, it gives me "cannot use import outside of a module" and using "require" statement gives me "require is not defined" error.
I searched online and found a solution of using "Browserify". However, in browserify, they include scripts in html file, when I don't have any html file. I want to load js files into the js file.

scripttag.js (I want to include filesystem and firebase-admin in the file)

```
var fs = require('fs');
console.log('this is me script tag!!!!!!!!')
const header = $('header.site-header').parent();

header.prepend('<div>Hello this is coming from the public folder </div>').css({'background-color':'orange', 'text-align': 'center'})

function addWishList(customer, productid){
/*
  fetch(`url`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': ,
      "X-Shopify-Access-Token": ,
    },
    body: 
    }})
  })

*/

    console.log('adding item to the wishlist!!')
}

function removeWishList(){
    console.log('removing item from the wishlist!!')
}

// const b1 = $('button.wishlist-btn');
// b1.on("click", addWishList);
 var wishbtn = document.querySelector('.wishlist-btn')
 wishbtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
     if(this.classList.contains('active')){             //condition to check if the button is already pressed
        removeWishList();
        this.classList.remove('active');
        this.innerHTML = 'Add to wishlist'
     }
     else{
        var customer = wishbtn.dataset.customer;
        if(customer == null || customer == ''){
            console.log('bhai log in kro')
        }
        else{
            var productid = wishbtn.dataset.product;
            this.classList.add('active');      //when the user presses add to wishlist button, it add active to the button's class
            this.innerHTML = 'Remove from wishlist'
            addWishList(customer, productid);
        }
       
   //     console.log(customer);
   //     console.log(productid)
        
  //      wishbtn.innerHTML= 'added to the wishlisht'
     }
     
 })
```

Comment: bad news is: you can't use `fs` module in browsers ... the good news is: `<script type="module">` enables ESM in there.

Comment: Yes, but I get CORS blocked error in the browser when I use type = "module"

Answer (score 1):

You can enable ES Modules by changing the `<script>` tag you load your file in with to

```
<script type="module" src="<your scriptfile"></script>
```

Comment: Actually, I don't load my file using this script tag. Instead, I'm using Shopify's SCRIPT_TAG API which loads remote JavaScript into a shop's storefront. This way, I can access the store's elements in my app.